# using active model serializer to nest the same model based on criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I want to use active model serializer for serializing JSON. The problem is that the nesting needs to be on the same model based on some criteria e.g.

my model is

```
name  | code | description     | group_name | group_code
--------------------------------------------------------
adhir | ad   | some desc       | grp1       | g1
aima  | ai   | some other desc | grp1       | g1
```

I want the JSON to look like

```
[
  { 
    group_name: grp1, 
    group_code: g1, 
    values: [
      { 
        name: adhir, 
        code: ad, 
        desc: some desc
      }, 
      { 
        name: aima, 
        code: ai, 
        desc: some other description
      }
    ]
```

all help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is possible to implement in plain active-model-serializers. You may combine it with simple JSON generation. Moreover, you may insert your own serializer inside map.

```rb
 Category
   .all
   .group_by { |category| [category.group_name, category.group_code] }
   .map do |key, records|
   {
     group_name: key[0],
     group_code: key[1],
     values: records.map { |record| CategoriesSerializer.new(record, {}).attributes }
   }
 end
```

With a serializer:

```rb
 class CategoriesSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :name, :code, :description
 end
```